# Read data recursively from a web API (OSISoft PI) using R

Tags: r, recursion, osisoft

Apologies in advance for a somewhat vague post - I'm reading confidential data and can't share the data itself or the exact means to access it.

I'm writing an R function to retrieve some experimental data between two timestamps (`start_time` & `end_time`) from PI Web API for a given equipment (`webid`). In some cases I may want to retrieve up to 100,000 rows but each API call returns a maximum of 1000 rows of data. The observations are at unequal intervals so it's not always known how many rows are to be retrieved for a given `start_time` and `end_time`.

My current approach is to use a `while` loop - simplified logic below:

```
while(difftime(time1 = end_time, time2 = t1, units = hours) > 1){
  dat <- rbind(dat, PiRead(start_time = t1, end_time = end_time, webid = webid)
  t1 <- max(dat$time)
}
```

Where `PiRead` is a function that returns data for a given `start_time`, `end_time` and `webid` (equipment), and `t1` is the max time in the data retrieved from the current API call. I'm always retrieving historical data and a gap of 1 hour is acceptable. The `while` loop works but I'd like to make a recursive function.

Here's what I have so far:

```
recursiveRead <- function(start_time, end_time, webid){
  dat <- PiRead(start_time = start_time, end_time = end_time, webid = webid)
  if(abs(difftime(time1 = dat[, max(time)], time2 = end_time, units = 'hours'))) <= 1){
    return(dat)
  }else{
    cat(sprintf('\nDesired End Time: %s\tCurrent End Time: %s\n', end_time, dat[, max(time)]))
    return(rbind(dat, 
                 recursiveRead(start_time = dat[, max(time)], end_time = end_time, webid = webid)))
  }
  
}
```

When executed, the two times printed to console (via the `cat` statement) are identical and R is stuck an infinite loop. Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you produce an exact piece of data that is not confidential? Basically, readers may want to have a file and a piece of code they can run with no modifications.

Comment: Are you just trying to return all the data available during that time period or are you interested in writing a recursive function? If you are just interested in returning the data, try using the maxCount URL parameter. ``` https://localhost/piwebapi/streams/myWEBID/recorded?starttime=xxx&endtime=xxx&maxCount=100000 ```. Each web request returns a single item or collection of items; this property limits the maximum number of returned items; it affects the Stream and StreamSet controllers, as well as any action for any controller that contains a maxCount URL parameter.

Comment: @NicholasStom I want to read data for the entire range - via a recursive function. The max. count for "recorded" values is 150,000 - the dates I'm querying have 2-10 times that many rows.

Comment: Ok, understood. Lets start the trouble shooting by looking at your PiRead function. Lets say you are asking for data between 01-01-2020 and 31-12-2020. Because you have so much data the time/data on the returned response the last value should be 01-05-2020. Run the PiRead function once and can you get the largest/last time on the response and print that?